# Android: Using canvas to draw on an imageview

Tags: java, android, button, geometry, ondraw

Right now I have an activity that displays an image. I want to be able to draw a circle on the image. The 'draw' button is supposed to draw a circle on the image, but for some reason it overwrites the original bitmap instead of drawing on top of it.

How can I make the button put a circle on the original bitmap/imageview instead of making a whole new one?

```
public class ImageDisplayActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static final String KEY_PATH = "img.jpg";
    private ZoomInZoomOut touch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_display);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(ImageDisplayActivity.KEY_PATH);
        try {
            java.io.FileInputStream in = this.openFileInput(path);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            touch = (ZoomInZoomOut) findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID);
            touch = arrangeImageView(touch);
            touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            in.close();
            Button draw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.draw);
            draw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200,
                            200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageBitmap);
                    Paint p = new Paint();
                    p.setAntiAlias(true);
                    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 5, p);
                    touch.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private ZoomInZoomOut arrangeImageView(ZoomInZoomOut img) {
        try {
            img.setRotation(90);
            img.setScaleX(1.8f);
            img.setScaleY(1.8f);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SetImageBitmap replaces the current bitmap with the new one.  It does not draw on top of it.  Easiest way to fix this is to get the bitmap from the image view, draw it to the imageBitmap, then draw the circle to the imageBitmap.

Comment: In terms of code, how would I go about drawing the bitmap to the imageBitmap?

Comment: canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap).  If you don't have the original bitmap, use the drawing cache or the imageView.getDrawable and drawable.draw(canvas)